# Truncate large data with More hyperlink which opens as a popup in php

Tags: javascript, php, popup

Iam trying to truncate a large data using php. Its truncating fine with 25 characters but when i click the More link it should open a pop up window with $original_text variable. Iam not sure how i can achieve that. Can anyone help me pls on this.

```
$length_limit = 25; //limit to this number of characters
$actual_length = strlen($value); //count characters in the $value
$original_text = $value;
$truncated_text = substr($value,0,$length_limit); //picks up characters from left to right starting at position zero all the way to 25

//Truncate if exceeds $chars value!
if($actual_length <= $length_limit){
$value = $original_text;
} else {
$value = $truncated_text." ... <a href='javascript:void(0);'>more</a>";
}
```

Comment: Anyone to help me plss

Comment: Anyone to guide me plss

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Store the truncated value in a separate variable like $truncate and show it like:

```
echo $truncate.' <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show_more">... show more</a>';
echo '<div id="show_more_popup" style="display:none;">'.$value.'</div>';
// At the same time make a div in which full text is there
```

Jquery: Now on click of show_more show the popup

```
$('#show_more').click(function(){
   // show the show_more_popup popup
});
```

Comment: Is there a way i can achieve this without jquery?

Comment: Yes you can, but to show popup using JS is a little bit tough task for you. Jquery provide very easy to use libraries for popup.

Comment: ok i understand. Not well versed with jquery. Need to work on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

With normal javascript :

```
echo $truncate.' <a onclick="alert(\"'.$truncate.'\")">... show more</a>';
```

Comment: I tried with the code below, but its not working. $value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick='alert(\"'.$original_text.'\")'>more</a>";

Comment: $value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick='alert(\"'.$original_text.'\")'>more</a>";........Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Need to find another way to make it work.